# Drawn arc is distorted in FF

Tags: css

I am trying to draw an arc inside a circle using this code:

```
<div class="outer_circle">
 <div class='arc1'></div>
 <div class='arc2'></div>
</div>
```

test here: http://jsfiddle.net/C9vVN/

The code works for Chrome,IE and Opera but in Firefox it looks distorted.
[image]
Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't ask me how but try `border-radius: 38%;` on the `.arc1:before` and `.arc2:before` for firefox.

Comment: @Prix I need the code to work cross browser not fix it for FF and make it look distorted everywhere else

Comment: That's exactly why I posted as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

box-sizing requires the `-moz` prefix for firefox ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)).

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9tXw/2/).

Comment: Personally I would always put non-prefixed version after prefixed version, and use CSS3 [pseudo element syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) `::before` instead of CSS2 [pseudo class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) `:before`: http://jsfiddle.net/T9tXw/1/ But your solution works already.

Comment: @Passerby You're right, the vendor prefixes should come [before the standard implementations](http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/). Are there any browsers that support the CSS3 syntax and not the CSS2? I know [IE8 only supports the single-colon syntax](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent) but it is getting rather old.

Comment: IE8 will never work on this page since it needs `transform`, so using double colon is a way to "filter" old browsers.